# How do I create a stream in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have a function that takes a `stream` as a parameter:

```
  startUpload(stream, filename) {
    const upload = this.s3.upload({
      Bucket: this.bucket,
      ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
      SSEKMSKeyId: this.s3SseKmsKeyId,
      Key: `${this.key}/${filename}`,
      Body: stream
    }, { partSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1 });
  }
```

How do I create a stream and write data to it?

Comment: I'd check both the
[nodejs documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_types_of_streams) and [this potentially relevent example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-example-creating-buckets-upload-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code works fine for me

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KeyId,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_secret,
        // region:process.env.AWS_region  
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3({   signatureVersion: 'v4',  })
var multer = require('multer')
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3')
var photoBucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: 'carwhapps'
    }
})
// let source is like req.files.filename or test with static file like ./public/test.jpg
photoBucket.upload({
        ACL: 'public-read', 
        Body: fs.createReadStream(source), 
        Key: filename,
        ContentType: 'application/octet-stream' // force download if it's accessed as a top location
},(err, response)=>{
    console.log(err, response)

})
```

Comment: Except I'm not reading from a file. I'm trying to write directly to the stream.

Comment: ok i already mention in express app with connect multiparty plugin you got file in req.files object and post file directly send to createReadStream() check me comment, provided that here you are not saving file in disk and http request already come to server as stream